# Why does the built-in "with" template tag in django result in duplicate queries

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

In the django docs for the ["with" template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with), it says that this tag..

> is useful when accessing an “expensive” method (e.g., one that hits the database) multiple times.

However, when I use it in my own template, I've observed (using [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) that each time I call the variable that I create using the "with" template tag, it results in duplicate queries to the database if I perform an operation on that variable within another template tag. Why is this the case? Shouldn't I be able to do things to that variable without it querying the database?

Below is my abridged and simplified code.

## Background

### I have three models:

```
## models.py
class Contributor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Contribution(models.Model):
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(
        Contributor, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='contributions'
    )
    class ROLE_CHOICES(models.TextChoices):
        A = 'AUTHOR', _('Author')
        C = 'COAUTHOR', _('Co-Author')
        E = 'EDITOR', _('Editor')
        V = 'VOICE', _('Voice Actor')
        S = 'AUDIO', _('Audio Engineer')

    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLE_CHOICES.choices)

class Scenario(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contributions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Contribution, related_name='contributions'
    )
```

### The template is associated with a class-based detail view:

```
## views.py
class ScenarioDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Scenario
```

Here is my custom template tag code:

```
## custom_tags.py
@register.filter
def only_role(scenario, test_role):
    return scenario.contributions.filter(role=test_role)
```

### Here is my template:

```
scenario_detail.html

{% load custom_tags %}

<dl>
{% with authors=scenario|only_role:"AUTHOR" %}
  {% if authors.count > 0 %}
    <dt>Author{{ authors.count|pluralize }}</dt>
    {% for contribution in authors %}
      <dd>{{ contribution.contributor.name }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {% comment %}The code in the "if" block would be repeated for all the possible roles, and I would add a variable to the "with" template tag for each role.{% endcomment %}
{% endwith %}
</dl>
```

## Problem

Here are the **duplicate queries** on the django debug toolbar readout:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "scenario_contribution" INNER JOIN "scenario_scenario_contributions" ON ("scenario_contribution"."id" = "scenario_scenario_contributions"."contribution_id") WHERE ("scenario_scenario_contributions"."scenario_id" = 'demo' AND "scenario_contribution"."role" = 'AUTHOR')
 2 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.        2.76    
Sel Expl

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "scenario_contribution" INNER JOIN "scenario_scenario_contributions" ON ("scenario_contribution"."id" = "scenario_scenario_contributions"."contribution_id") WHERE ("scenario_scenario_contributions"."scenario_id" = 'demo' AND "scenario_contribution"."role" = 'AUTHOR')
 2 similar queries.  Duplicated 2 times.        0.72    
Sel Expl
    
SELECT ••• FROM "scenario_contribution" INNER JOIN "scenario_scenario_contributions" ON ("scenario_contribution"."id" = "scenario_scenario_contributions"."contribution_id") INNER JOIN "scenario_contributor" ON ("scenario_contribution"."contributor_id" = "scenario_contributor"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "scenario_participant" ON ("scenario_contribution"."character_id" = "scenario_participant"."id") WHERE ("scenario_scenario_contributions"."scenario_id" = 'demo' AND "scenario_contribution"."role" = 'AUTHOR') ORDER BY "scenario_contributor"."last_name" ASC, "scenario_contributor"."first_name" ASC, "scenario_contribution"."role" ASC, "scenario_participant"."part_type" ASC, "scenario_participant"."designation" ASC
```

Do the duplicate queries stem from the fact that I'm using the "count" method on the variable "authors"? I tried the dummy template code below, and it dropped the number of queries by 2, so that would suggest this is the case.

## Attempted Solutions

### Dummy Template Code

```
{% with authors=scenario|only_role:"AUTHOR" %}
  {% if authors %}
    <dt>{{ authors }}</dt>
    {% for contribution in authors %}
      <dd>{{ contribution.contributor.first_name }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

If so, how might I, for example, return the count information in a single custom tag? Can I return two values in one custom tag, or would I need a separate custom tag? (in other words, have one custom tag that returns a filtered queryset as well as the number of objects). I've written a custom tag that counts the number of objects, and I've gotten the number of queries for this specific block of template down to 2 instead of 3 by using it, but it would be nice to have it down to 1 query.

### Count Custom Template Tag

```
@register.filter
def num_role(scenario, test_role):
    return scenario.contributions.filter(role=test_role).count
```

### Revised Template Code

```
scenario_detail.html

{% load custom_tags %}

<dl>
{% with authors=scenario|only_role:"AUTHOR" n_authors=scenario|num_role:"AUTHOR" %}
  {% if n_authors > 0 %}
    <dt>Author{{ n_authors|pluralize }}</dt>
    {% for contribution in authors %}
      <dd>{{ contribution.contributor.name }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {% comment %}The code in the "if" block would be repeated for all the possible roles, and I would add a variable to the "with" template tag for each role.{% endcomment %}
{% endwith %}
</dl>
```

Comment: Use `{% if authors|length %}`, don't use `.count`, but `|length` if you will enumerate over the queryset anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case? Shouldn't I be able to do things to that variable without it querying the database?

A `QuerySet` does *not* query the database, or at least not instantly when it is constructed. It is basically a *promise* to query the database when necessary, and `.count()` thus will query the database. You constructed one `QuerySet`, but this will make multiple queries.

A `QuerySet` can however cache the result if it is evaluated. If you use `len(…)` it does not *count* the records, or at least by a query, it *loads* the records, and then checks how many records have been loaded.

We can exploit this to work with the [**`|length`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#length), which will force evaluation of the `QuerySet`, and can be reused:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

<dl>
{% with authors=scenario|only_role:"AUTHOR" %}
  {% if authors|length %}
    <dt>Author{{ authors|length|pluralize }}</dt>
    {% for contribution in authors %}
      <dd>{{ contribution.contributor.name }}</dd>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
</dl>
```

The `{% if authors|length %}` can also be replaced with `{% if authors %}`, since a `QuerySet` has truthiness `True` if it contains at least one record.

Comment: That brought it down to zero duplicate queries. Thanks!